# Upgrade MySql schema, upgrade schema VS fresh install + data migration

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I will be deploying my application in a few weeks for production.
technologies used are Java,Hibernate and MySQL.

I need to decide the upgrade strategy for this application. This application will have a single production installation and a few test installations all managed by us.

Since the app is under development it may require frequent upgrades 3 or 4 times a month.
Initially amount of data will be less.

One ways is to upgrade schema

1. version each release when schema changes.
2. Write sql diffs like diff_v1_v2.sql, diff_v2_v3.sql etc
3. At upgrade let application logic apply the diff files and upgrade schema on production server to latest release.

Second approach is to 
 1. Do a fresh install of application
 2. write migration script to migrate data from older version to latest version

My preference is to go with the first approach. Any other approach which we can take.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use [FlywayDB](http://flywaydb.org/) or [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) to migrate.

Comment: Thanks JB. I will read these and post it here if it solves my usecase.

Comment: I saw both and liked http://flywaydb.org/ for its simplicity. It can solve the applying of SQL diffs. Any recommendations for generating the diff files, And also for validating that diff files plus _ flyway did all the required schema changes?

Comment: The best way is to use FlywayDB exclusively to generate and migrate the database schema, even during development. That way, developers always use a schema generated with Flyway, and test the scripts continuously.